# jQuery dataTable : How to know width applied to each column

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm creating two tables, one for normal rows (table1), and another for total row(s) (-table2).
I would like to have the width for table1 automatic , and apply same widths to table2.
I tried to get the widths of table1 in table 2 drawCallback and apply the same :

```
"fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
  var i=0;
  jQuery('#table1 tbody tr:last td').each(function () {
    jQuery('#table2 tbody tr td:eq(' + i + ')').width(jQuery(this).width());
    i++;
  });
}
```

But sometimes, the width of table1 last row is returned as 0.
So, is there any way, that I can query the data table1 object, and get the width applied for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dataTables set the width of the `<th>` elements, not `<tbody>` `<td>`'s. If you are not adding inline CSS to your headers (and basically that should never be necessary) the easiest is simply to copy dataTables injected `style` attribute, which contains the calculated widths `"width: 63px;"` etc :

```js
drawCallback: function() {
   jQuery('#table1 thead th').each(function(i,th) {
      jQuery('#table2 thead th:eq('+i+')')
         .attr('style', jQuery(th).attr('style')) 
   })
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/51jLt8og/**